# Should I wait for OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, xcode

I'm developing with XCode, but just realized the newest version requires that I upgrade to OS X Mountain Lion, which I am quite against as I don't need the (useless!) features. The upgrade itself is 19.99, and with Maverick's release right around the corner, will this just be a waste of money? Will upgrading to Mavericks from Mountain Lion be the same cost as upgrading from Lion?

Comment: This might be better suited to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You have various questions in this, unfortunately they are mostly conjecture.  Should you wait?  That's primarily subjective - if you need it to develop and can't wait - then probably not.  Otherwise, may as well.

Comment: Ahh, yes…this should probably be closed as too localized (subjective).

Answer (score 0):

> Will upgrading to Mavericks from Mountain Lion be the same cost as upgrading from Lion?

Probably. That is how it was with Mountain Lion & Lion.

Comment: I think this answer should be deleted as it is obsolete. We now all know that it's a "free" update (if your time is free, too :).